# Отсортировать массив по алфавиту, сохранив ключи

Tags: массивы, javascript, объекты

Ребят, помогите разобраться с таким делом.

Имеем обьект городов:

```
var cities = {213:'Москва',2:'Санкт-Петербург',5:'Иваново');
```

Необходимо перевести его в ассоциативный массив такого вида:

```
var cities_arr = new Array()
cities_arr['213'] = 'Москва';
cities_arr['2'] = 'Санкт-Петербург';
cities_arr['5'] = 'Иваново');
```

Это ладно, сделаем `for in`-ом

Затем отсортировать этот массив по алфавиту.

Что-то на подобие:
    cities_arr.sort();

Но при этом сохранить ключи, т.е. `sort` отдает нам только отсортированный массив без ключей.

Чтобы у нас получился массив такого вида:

```
cities_arr['5'] = 'Иваново');
cities_arr['213'] = 'Москва';
cities_arr['2'] = 'Санкт-Петербург';
```

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Чёт я сомневаюсь, что у вас выполнится подобная конструкция:

     new Array('213' = 'Москва', '2' = 'Санкт-Петербург', '5' = 'Иваново');

Comment: @Denis Masster - вам в книгу из разряда JS для чайников.

###### ассоциативный обьект? O_o А такие бывают? xD

Кстати, задача у вас просто абсурдна (вернее то, как вы мыслите для ее решения). И еще - за такое:

     var cities_arr = new Array()
     cities_arr[213] = 'Москва';

надо наказывать :)

Comment: ну не суть, я поменял

Comment: @AlexWindHope, харошь придираться ))

Comment: объясните мне, чем отличается:

     cities_arr['213'] = 'Москва';
     cities_arr['2'] = 'Санкт-Петербург';
     cities_arr['5'] = 'Иваново';

от:

     cities_arr['5'] = 'Иваново';
     cities_arr['213'] = 'Москва';
     cities_arr['2'] = 'Санкт-Петербург';

Comment: Инструкция создания массива как привел автор действительно не выполняется. Но если у него такая задача - я ответ написал ниже.

Comment: Вопрос на засыпку - какой смысл менять местами значение хэша?.. О_о

Comment: @Spectre, да прошу прощения.. пример не лучший. в нижнем массив отсортирован по алфавиту

Comment: > Вопрос на засыпку - какой смысл менять местами значение хэша?

Очевидно же, что ТС нужен упорядоченный словарь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Массивы в JavaScript не хранят последовательность ключей, по этому в вашем случае нужно хранить ее явно в отдельном списке:

```
keys = ['5', '213', '2']
values = {'5': 'Иваново', '213': 'Москва', '2': 'Санкт-Петербург'}
for (var i in keys) {
  values[keys[i]]; //...
}
```

Для удобства можно обернуть это в класс, однако в этом случае работать с массивом придется через свои методы. Работа с классами в JavaScript слишком неуклюжа, по этому написал пример на [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/). Пример на чистом JavaScript в конце поста:

```
class OrderedArray
  constructor: ->
    @keys = []
    @values = {}

  set: (key, value) ->
    @keys.push(key)
    @values[key] = value

  get: (key) ->
    @values[key]

  remove: (key) ->
    @keys = (k for k in @keys when k != key)
    delete @values[key]

  each: (fn) ->
    fn k, @values[k] for k in @keys
    return
```

Соответственно, если выполнить ваш пример:

```
var cities_arr = new OrderedArray();      
cities_arr.set('5', 'Иваново');
cities_arr.set('213', 'Москва');
cities_arr.set('2', 'Санкт-Петербург');

cities_arr.each(function(key, value) {
  return console.log(key, value);
});
```

На выходе получим:

```
5 Иваново
213 Москва
2 Санкт-Петербург
```

**UPD.** Класс на чистом JavaScript:

```
var OrderedArray;

OrderedArray = (function() {

  function OrderedArray() {
    this.keys = [];
    this.values = {};
  }

  OrderedArray.prototype.set = function(key, value) {
    this.keys.push(key);
    return this.values[key] = value;
  };

  OrderedArray.prototype.get = function(key) {
    return this.values[key];
  };

  OrderedArray.prototype.remove = function(key) {
    var k;
    this.keys = (function() {
      var _i, _len, _ref, _results;
      _ref = this.keys;
      _results = [];
      for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
        k = _ref[_i];
        if (k !== key) {
          _results.push(k);
        }
      }
      return _results;
    }).call(this);
    return delete this.values[key];
  };
  OrderedArray.prototype.each = function(fn) {
    var k, _i, _len, _ref;
    _ref = this.keys;
    for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
      k = _ref[_i];
      fn(k, this.values[k]);
    }
  };

  return OrderedArray;

})();
```

Comment: могу ошибаться, но `k for k in @keys when k != key`, и ссылки у вас битые, к тому же ТС`у нужен порядок значений - не ключей

>Работа с классами в JavaScript слишком неуклюжа

годный вброс

Comment: > могу ошибаться, но k for k in @keys when k != key

Поставил именно `if` по наитию, видимо синтаксис питона сказывается :) Однако, проверил - работает и с `if`.

> и ссылки у вас битые

Похоже, это баг хэшкода.

> годный вброс

Только не говорите, что мол в JavaScript нет классов и, что это вообще не JavaScript-way.

Comment: > Однако, проверил - работает и с if.

нифига:

    cities_arr.remove(213);
    Unhandled Error: Undefined variable: b

>годный вброс

я не ведусь на провокации, но ваш метод `remove` не рабочий в принципе, даже не смотря на перемнную `b`

Comment: @Spectre, посыпаю голову пеплом, не туда посмотрел. Исправил на `when`.

> я не ведусь на провокации

Вот и отлично, на сем предлагаю демагогию закончить.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы не стал так делать, а вставил бы промежуточную стадию:

1. Вытащить все key из объекта и положить в массив.
2. Отсортировать массив.
3. Создать новый пустой массив и пробегая по ключам отсортированного массива запихивать данные.

-

```
var indexes = [];
for (var key in cities) {
    indexes.push(key);
}
indexes.sort();
var newArr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < indexes.length; i += 1) {
    key = indexes[i];
    newArr[key] = cities[key];
}
```

UPD

Нельзя видимо больше 10 комментариев. Если нужна сортировка по имени - создай массив из имен и отсортируй.
    var indexes = ['к', 'в', 'ы'];
    indexes.sort();
    alert(indexes);

Comment: ИМХО: Я вообще бы с объектом работал без всяких массивов.

Comment: допустим:

    var cities = {213:'Москва',2:'Санкт-Петербург',5:'Иваново');

тогда `newArr` будет выглядеть так:

    newArr[0] = 'undefined'
    newArr[1] = 'undefined'
    newArr[2] = 'Санкт-Петербург'
    newArr[3] = 'undefined'
    newArr[4] = 'undefined'
    newArr[5] = 'Иваново'
    ...
    newArr[6..212] =  'undefined'
    newArr[213] = 'Москва'

смысл от такого массива? `length` будет 214, но элемента 3, не в цикле не пройтись ничего другого полезного не сделать...

Comment: не, такое не подходит :(

Comment: Да, но не моя проблема ) Дали задачу - надо массив, в котором по данным индексам стоят значения - получите такой массив. И еще в комментариях AlexWindHope заметил, что хэши менять местами бессмысленно.

Comment: @Denis Masster, да в вашем случае совсем не массив нужен, т.е. массив, но объектов:

    var cities = [
        {
            'id': 2,
            'name': 'Санкт-Петербург'
        },
        {
            'id': 5,
            'name': 'Иваново'
        },
        {
            'id': 213,
            'name': 'Москва'
        },
    ];
    cities.sort(function(a,b){
        if(a.name == b.name){
            return 0;
        }
        return a.name < b.name ? -1 : 1;
    });

Comment: @Denis Masster Тогда уточните задачу. Код, который решает поставленную задачу - я привел.

Comment: стоит задуматься о создании временного массива вида

    var data = [{index:123, name:'Moscow'}, ...];

Иначе вы не отсортируете.

По поводу менять местами значение хэша:

     var o = { a:true, b:true };
     o.b='trololo';
     o.a='ololo'; 
     for( var i in o ) {
        console.log(i);
     }
     // -> a, b
     // и смысл? :)

****
    // ....
    newArr[key] = cities[key]; // no comments ^_^
    // ....

Весело у вас тут :D

Comment: @AlexWindHope А что плохого в newArr[key] = cities[key]; ? А то останусь несведущим. Расскажите пожалуйста?

Comment: Вам же @Spectre написал. А по поводу по очередности действий написал я ( в случае массива смысл точно такой-же как и описанный мною, т.е. никакого )

Comment: да уж, прикол не удался..
javascript выводит элементы объекта по ключу, я надеялся что если перевести это в ассоциативный массив и расположить елементы как мне нужно, он будет выводить их в той последовательности в которой я указал. но это не так. в ассоциативном массиве он также всё выводит по номеру ключа. :(  мне это нужно для приложения на слабом телефоне и сортировать на телефоне никак не вариант. есть еще какие-то способы заставить javascript выводить елементы массива по алфавиту а не значению ключа?